# How can i set the x axis tick interval to be 1 in C3 / d3 js charts?

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I'm very new to chart building with c3 and d3. I've done a search, but I can't find an answer - could anyone help? how can I force the x axis to display every tick mark - it is currently displaying every other one. I want the chart to be dynamic, so I don't want to have to hard wire in the tick count (it is pulling data from elsewhere).
I hope I've made sense! Grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust **culling** option:

```
axis: {
  x: {
    tick: {
      culling: false
    }
  }
}
```

See [docs](http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-culling).

---

Also, you can force visibility of first and last tick value with little css hack:

```
.c3-axis-x g.tick:nth-last-child(2) text,
.c3-axis-x g.tick:nth-child(2) text {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you loads - I thought I had tried this and it hadn't worked, but obviously I hadn't done it properly! Brilliant, thank you.

Comment: I might be asking too much now, but is there a way to force it to show the first and last tick, and then go with the default culling in between?

Comment: @Sarah yes, this can be done with css, see added code in answer.

Comment: Oooo you're brilliant, thank you!! that works perfectly. In case you're not sick of me yet, is there anyway to do the same for the y axis - i.e. a way to display every tick mark - culling doesn't seem to be an option for the y axis. I imagine the same css hack could be used to force the first and last on the y axis to display (I'll go check now!)